# Delete field's machine-name in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, field, field-names

I'm trying to create a new field, but Drupal came up with the well-known error:

> The machine-readable name is already in use. It must be unique

I'm sure that the field doesn't exist anymore (I checked the fields' list and it doesn't show up).

I want to use that specific machine name because I already have developed some functions that are using that name.

So I guess the name is still saved in the database, there is a way to delete it without screw everything up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63421/how-to-manually-or-programmatically-delete-a-field) to manually delete the field from the database and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache or check if you can find a field with this machine name in reusable fields list.

Comment: Hi! Already done, and unfortunately the field doesn't appeared in the reusable fields. Now I'm trying to delete it manually from the database.